# Find $Re(z^{2n})$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$Re(z^{2n})$$

If we use $$z=rcis(\theta)=re^{i\theta}$$

$$z^{2n}=(rcis(\theta))^{2n}=(re^{i\theta})^{2n}$$

$$z^{2n}=r^{2n}cis(2n\cdot\theta)=re^{i\cdot 2n\cdot\theta}$$

$$Re(z^{2n})=r^{2n}\cos(2n\cdot\theta)=Re(re^{i\cdot 2n\cdot\theta})$$

What will $Re(re^{i\cdot 2n\cdot\theta})$ be? $$r^{2n}
\cdot\frac{e^{i\cdot2n\cdot\theta}-e^{i\cdot2n\cdot\theta}}{2}$$?

Comment: I don't understand your question, in what variables do you want your answer?

Comment: Everything was correct until the last expression which should be $r^{2n}\frac{e^{2ni\theta}+e^{-2ni\theta}}{2}$. Also,  $r^{2n}\cos(2n\theta)$ is probably a better answer to $\Re(z^{2n})$.

Comment: @Jacob Sorry forgot to raise $r$ to the $2n$ power

Answer (score 4):

Let $z = r e^{i \theta}$. Then
\begin{align}
\Re(z^{2n}) & = \Re (r^{2n} e^{2 i n \theta}) \\
& = r^{2n} \cos (2 n \theta).
\end{align}

Comment: What's new here? @gbox has already done that.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=a+ib$, $$Re(z^{n}) =  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2} \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k} $$ then substitute $2n$ to $n$  and simplify.